# Add pdf as tab in teams channel using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

we are trying to add pdf as tab in teams channel using graph api. The tab has been added in the channel but not able to preview it. I see the below error
[image: Pdf as a tab]
the post api graph call to add pdf as tab
POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/tabs](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteam-id%7D/channels/%7Bchannel-id%7D/tabs)

```
{
  "displayName": "word",
  "teamsApp@odata.bind" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.file.staticviewer.pdf",
  "configuration": {
     "entityId": "115A90F4-AC9C-4F79-9837-36D1EFB3BE08",
     "contentUrl": "https://m365x165177.sharepoint.com/sites/4NewCloneWithClonableParts/Shared%20Documents/General/Employee Handbook.pdf",
     "removeUrl": null,
     "websiteUrl": null
  }
}
```

referred the following api - [add configurable tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#example-create-a-configured-word-tab)

Comment: We tried this at our end and it is working fine - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptqud.png. Could you please confirm if you are passing the correct entityId, contentUrl?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, What should be the entityId for Documents ?.
we are trying to add a document from SharePoint. the Content URL which we add is absolute file path.

Comment: Please check this to get entityId & contentUrl - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#example-create-a-configured-word-tab:~:text=pdf-,The%20following%20is%20the%20configuration.,-Property.

Comment: We called GET /sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id} and webUrl from the response is the contentUrl and guid from cTag is the entityId. Please find the screenshots as below -https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMhso.png

Adding the PDF as tab - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLE0O.png

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT , We used entity id which is part of etag and the url as content url, 
added the tab, it is not preview able.

Comment: we are using the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{encodedurl}/driveItem?$expand=children, 
The response we have etag we are using the id for entityID and for the content url we are using (folderpath + filename)

Comment: Could you please try using the API calls mentioned here at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#example-create-a-configured-word-tab:~:text=pdf-,The%20following%20is%20the%20configuration.,-Property

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT, we have **sourcedoc=%7B{sourceDocId}%7D** for the Word documents, the same is not available for pdf when the document is opened from sharepoint in a new browser

Comment: Yes, we also could not find sourcedoc=%7B{sourceDocId}%7D for pdf. Could you please try using the API calls mentioned here at - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs#example-create-a-configured-word-tab:~:text=pdf-,The%20following%20is%20the%20configuration.,-Property

Comment: We don't have any groups or group Id's for SharePoint. We are using the graph endpoint](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{encodedurl}/driveItem?$expand=children). The response contains ctag, etag  "cTag": "\"c:{id},0\"", "eTag": "\"{id},1\"",` the id is similar to that of sourceId when doc is opened in browser. When we used the same ID as entityID we were able to add word doc as tab but it was not preview able. We get **Sorry, this file has been deleted or moved.** , if we use a guid without any hyphens **115A90F4AC9C4F79983736D1EFB3BE08**  it works for word document

Comment: we used the [same endpoind](graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares{encodedurl}/driveItem?$expand=children), the response contains PDF's. The pdf have cTag and etag. so we used the same id as entity Id. we were not able to preview pdf. we removed hyphens from the Id and tried to add pdf as tab it didnt work for pdf's.

Comment: we are using [Shares based graph endpoint to get driveitems][https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/{encodedurl}/driveItem?$expand=children] instead of  using (Groups based graph endpoint to get drive items)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http]

Comment: We are checking this internally; we will get back to you. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response, it is noticed that the PDF file name has a space in it that is not being encoded. Could you please properly encode the file name and try creating the tab again? Also, it would be good if you can share a Fiddle trace of the failing tab load since that would show exactly what file the tab is trying to load.
It would show us what call is being made to SharePoint to get the file and allow us to figure out why it's failing and resulting in this error being shown.

Comment: Could you please share above details?